# Fine Adjustment in Playback on Itunes

Tags: itunes

How do I do fine adjustment on the progress of video playback in iTunes?
For example, on the iPad, if you slide you finger down while holding onto the dot on the playback progress bar, you will go into fine adjustment mode and you track the progress second by second.

Btw, I'm on OS x

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's helpful.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnhFxY40C_w

Comment: Can you add some text about why you consider the video to be helpful and what is actually in it?

Comment: Sure. The video demonstrates who to fast forward or fast rewind in an alternate way. It's not exactly the same as on the iOS but it may be useful to navigate more precisely.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment. I'm pretty new to stack exchange. :-)
Continue my first comment:
The video uses the quicktime player and i assume it works in iTunes too. But I haven't tested.
You can enter the alternate fast forward/rewind by click and hold the pause button while a video is playing.